Change TextInput with onSubmitEditing seems to reload the animation
I have a login flow for a mobile app that opens an overlay when the user presses the log-in button. This overlay features an animation that slides in from the bottom of the screen, covering approximately 30% of it.
My problem is that when the user enters their email and presses the "Next" button on the keyboard, I want the cursor to move to the password input field.
While the cursor does change as expected, the animation seems to reload quickly during this transition, does anyone knows how to fix this?
const Login = ({ isLoginPressed, isBackgroundPressed }) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState("");

  const passwordInputRef = React.useRef(null);

  const handleEmailSubmit = () => {
    passwordInputRef.current.focus();
  };

  const translateY = useAnimatedBottom(isLoginPressed || isBackgroundPressed);

  return (
      <Animated.View
        style={[styles.loginOverlay, { transform: [{ translateY }] }]}>
          <View style={[styles.container]}>
            <Text style={[styles.title]} variant="headlineMedium">Log in</Text>
            <View>
              <TextInput
                style={[styles.textInput]}
                placeholder='Email'
                clearButtonMode='always'
                inputMode='email'
                autoCapitalize='none'
                autoFocus={true}
                returnKeyType="next"
                onSubmitEditing={handleEmailSubmit}
                value={email}
                onChangeText={setEmail}
              />
              <TextInput
                ref={passwordInputRef}
                style={[styles.textInput]}
                placeholder='Password'
                clearButtonMode='always'
                keyboardType="default"
                autoCapitalize='none'
                secureTextEntry={true}
                returnKeyType="done"
                onSubmitEditing={() => {
                  console.log('Submit key pressed');
                }}
                value={password}
                onChangeText={setPassword}
              />
              <View style={[styles.buttonContainer]}>
                <Button
                  mode="contained"
                  style={[styles.button]}
                  buttonColor="#ffffff"
                  textColor="#136E0B"
                  labelStyle={styles.buttonText}
                >
                  Log in
                </Button>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
      </Animated.View>
  );
};

